# Calculate the probability of mu for normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

Given we have drawn $n$ samples $x_1,...x_N$ from a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$. How do I calculate the probability that eg $\mu=1$? ie $P(\mu=1|x_1,...x_N)$

Is it simply $1-\alpha$ of a T-distribution for $\mu=1$?

And taking this forward: How do I calculate the probability that this $\mu$ is drawn from a Normal distribution with e.g. $\mu_2=1$ and $\sigma_2=0.5$?

Comment: I don't think this question is clear, so maybe you could try rephrasing it.  You already are given $\mu$ so why would you want to calculate the probably of $\mu$?  Are you trying to estimate the parameter $\mu$ given the data?

Comment: Sorry, but mu is not given, you can only calculate an estimator of mu (mu-Hat) by averaging x1,..xN. Say mu-Hat is 0.99, how do I calculate the probabilty that the true mu is 2?

Comment: I think you got this wrong - mu is an unknown constant (there is nothing random about it), so it doesn't make sense to compute the probability you listed.  What would make sense is to compute a probability involving the random quantity x_bar = (x1 + ... + xN)/N. For example, what is the probability that x_bar falls between the values 0.5 and 1.5?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it not possible to calculate a probability that an unknown constant equals to a certain value? How would I calculate the probability for x_bar?

Comment: With a continuous distribution, the probability that a random variable takes on a specific value is 0.  Perhaps you are interested in determining if $\mu$ falls between certain fails or a small range?

You can obtain estimates for $\mu$ using something like Maximum Likelihood, but I'm not sure that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: @StatsStudent Probability of a parameter would be Bayesian, right? If that's the case, then why not use a discrete prior?

Comment: I suppose there are a few approaches to this, but I'm not convinced that this is what the OP is truly after.

Comment: After reading up on it I think the maximum likelihood estimator seems the right thing. @StatsStudent: Thanks! Dave: How would you do it with bayes?

Comment: @StanW You would calculate the posterior distribution, using some discrete prior, and then find the probability that the posterior equals what you're looking for. But I don't think that's what you're looking for. I think what you want is the regular t-test. Are you looking for a p-value or a regular hypothesis test? Do those terms ring any bells?

Comment: To assign a probability to $\mu$ would require something like a Bayesian approach; but in a Bayesian approach, unless your prior assigns positive probability to the exact value $\mu=1$, the posterior probability of it would be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that $\mu=1$ given a sample with a non-degenerate prior density is zero.

$$\Pr(\mu|X,\sigma^2)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\prod_{i=1}^nf(X|\mu,\sigma^2)\pi(\mu,\sigma^2)}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_0^\infty{\prod_{i=1}^nf(X|\mu,\sigma^2)\pi(\mu,\sigma^2)}\mathrm{d}\mu\mathrm{d}\sigma^2}\mathrm{d}\sigma^2,$$ where $f$ is the Gaussian likelihood function.

At $\mu=1$ the density function has height but zero width.

Alternatively, you could construct the same discussion by noting that a countable point in a continuum of countable points has zero measure and therefore zero probability.

To discuss the probability of $\mu$ having some value there has to be a range, even if very small.

The only exception to this would be a degenerate prior density or a prior with weight only on a countable set that caused the function to be countable.

My guess, though, is that this is not what you are really asking.  My guess is that you are really asking "what is the probability of seeing data as extreme or more extreme, given that $\mu=1$?"

That is $\Pr(X|\mu)$.  If the variance isn't known, then yes, that would be a Student t-distribution.  You would invert the t value from $$t=\frac{\bar{x}-1}{\sqrt{\frac{s^2}{n}}},$$ by looking it up on a table.

If you were really discussing the Bayesian solution rather than the Frequentist or maximum likelihood solution, then you would be in the subjective interpretation of Bayesian methods where $\mu$ is drawn from the prior.  In that case $$\pi(\mu;\sigma^2)=\mathcal{N}(1,.25).$$ based on your edit of $\mu=1,\sigma=.5$.

**EDIT**
Now I think I know less of what you are asking than with the first question.  It may help if you describe the underlying data and what you need to infer.  If you were writing out a set of hypotheses in formal writing, what would they be? Skip the goal method, that is irrelevant.  The method should follow not lead.

Comment: " probability of seeing the data that was observed, given that μ=1" = 0

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with an example. How would I calculate the probability that mu lies in a specific range?

Comment: What I also don‘t quite understand is if P(mu=1|X)=0, because 1 is a specific value, then the probability P(X|mu) should also be zero, right? because X are specific values from a continuum, but for a likelihood function you specifically calculate P(x1, ...,xn|mu, var) aussiming P(x|mu, var) as the value of distribution density at X.

Comment: @user158565 thanks for the catch.

Comment: I've deleted the second part of my question again, it did not help things. I think what I was looking for was the likelihood function, which is basically the distribution density function for $P(\mu|x)$, right? but just as the normal density function it does not give you a probability for a specific value, but for a range of values (when taking the area under the curve for that range).

Answer (score 1):

The probability that $\mu=1$ is zero: $P(\mu=1|X)=0$ if you're drawing $\mu$ from a continuous distribution.

If you want to apply inference techniques, then it's usually for intervals, such as $\mu<1$ or $0<\mu<1$.

Comment: This is a little glib in light of the deeper reasons indicated in comments to the question: namely, it doesn't even make sense to write "$P(\mu=1\mid\ldots)$" until additional assumptions are introduced.

Comment: @whuber, OP draws a random $\mu$, generates a sample $X$ from $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then tries to figure out what's the probability of $\mu=1$. I see nothing wrong with this, OP's doing some sort of bootstrapping. The only problem is that the probability is exactly zero assuming the distribution is continuous

Comment: @Dave, OP actually wrote $P(\mu=1|x_1,...x_N)$, i.e. conditional probability of population parameter given the dataset. OP's description of the process is also consistent with this notation, me thinks

Comment: We all once thought that's what a p-value means.